# Accept merge request without running manual stages

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a pipeline with 3 stages: `build`, `deploy-test` and `deploy-prod`. I want stages to have following behavior:

- always run `build`
- run `deploy-test` automatically when on `master` or manually when on other branches
- run `deploy-prod` manually, only available on `master` branch

My pipeline configuration seems to achieve that but I have a problem when trying to merge branches into master. I don't want to execute `deploy-test` stage on every branch before doing merge. Right now I am required to do that as the merge button is disabled with a message `Pipeline blocked. The pipeline for this merge request requires a manual action to proceed`. The setting `Pipelines must succeed` in project is disabled.

I tried adding additional rule to prevent `deploy-test` stage from running in merge requests but it didn't change anything:

```
rules:
   - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID'
     when: never
   - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
     when: on_success
   - when: manual
```

Full pipeline configuration:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy-test
  - deploy-prod

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "build"

deploy-test:
  stage: deploy-test
  script:
    - echo "deploy-test"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      when: on_success
    - when: manual

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy-prod
  script:
    - echo "deploy-prod"
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 7):

The only way I got it to work was to set `☑️ Skipped pipelines are considered successful` in `Setttings > General > Merge requests > Merge Checks`

[image: Gitlab Settings > General > Merge Checks with checked Skipped pipelines are considered successful option]

**and** marking the manual step as "allow_failure"

```yaml
upload:
  stage: 'upload'
  rules:
    # Only allow uploads for a pipeline source whitelisted here.
    # See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      when: 'manual'
      allow_failure: true
```

After this clicking the `Merge when Pipeline succeeds` button …
[image: Screenshot of Gitlab after pressing Merge when Pipeline success Button]

… will merge the MR without any manual interaction:

[image: Screenshot showing that the MR was merged without running the last step]

Comment: This was tested with gitlab `14.10.1-ee`

Comment: The project setting seems to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've opened a merge request from branch "mybranch" into "master" with the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: alpine

stages:
  - build
  - deploy-test
  - deploy-prod

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "build"

# run deploy-test automatically when on master or manually when on other branches
# Don't run on merge requests

deploy-test:
  stage: deploy-test
  script:
    - echo "deploy-test"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      when: on_success
    - when: manual


# run deploy-prod manually, only available on master branch

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy-prod
  script:
    - echo "deploy-prod"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      when: manual
```

Notes:

- `only` is deprecated, so I replaced it with `if`
- I added Alpine image to make the jobs run faster (slimmer container); it doesn't affect the logic

When I pushed changes to branch "mybranch", GitLab did the following:

- showed a blue "Merge when pipeline succeeds" button on my MR
- ran "build" stage
- skipped "deploy-prod" stage (only available on "master" branch)
- gave me a manual "play" button to run the job on "mybranch"
- at this point, the pipeline status is "blocked" and the MR is showing "Pipeline blocked. The pipeline for this merge request requires a manual action to proceed"
- now I manually start the "deploy-test" stage by selecting the Play icon in the Pipelines screen
- pipeline status indicator changes to "running" and then to "passed"
- my merge request shows the pipeline passed and gives me the green "Merge" button

Comment: I don't understand. You didn't really change anything important in the pipeline file. You also stated that You had to manually invoke `deploy-test` in merge request before being able to merge, it's not what I want. I want to skip invoking `deploy-test` stage in some merge requests.

Comment: Okay.  Could you please clarify your requirements?  You say you want to skip invoking `deploy-test` stage in some merge requests -- which ones?  Earlier you said you want to run `deploy-test` automatically when on `master` or manually when on other branches.

Comment: Well... those are exactly my requirements. I don't always want to run `deploy-test` from branches, so some merges will have the full branch pipeline (`build` and `-deploy-test`) completed and some won't. I want to be able to merge both but the message `Pipeline blocked. The pipeline for this merge request requires a manual action to proceed` prevents me from doing so.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for your patience in explaining your use case. See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/40458 — this is presently an open issue. You may want to upvote it if you can, to indicate demand to the developers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of variables that are available to the pipeline on runtime - [Predefined variables reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/13.10/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)
Some are available specifically for pipelines associated with merge requests - [Predefined variables for merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/13.10/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines)

You can utilize one or more of these variables to determine if you would want to run the deploy-test job for that merge request.

For example, you could use mention the phrase `"skip_cicd"` in your merge request title, access it with `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE` variable and create a rule. Your pipeline would look somewhat like this (**please do test the rule, I have edited the pipeline off the top of my head and could be wrong**) -

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy-test
  - deploy-prod

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "build"

deploy-test:
  stage: deploy-test
  script:
    - echo "deploy-test"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE == *"skip_cicd"*'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      when: on_success
    - when: manual

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy-prod
  script:
    - echo "deploy-prod"
  only:
    - master
```